# How to get id of an HTML element by using getElementsByName() method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to java script and I am practicing it and got stuck with a situation. Here, I want to print different ids of all the elements in HTML with same name. I used getElementsByName() method but after getting elements I don't know how to print them on scree.
For your reference, Here is the code which I tried.

```js
function showID(){
var circleName= document.getElementsByName("Circle");

document.write(circleName.id);
```

```html
<button onclick="showID()" name="Circle" id="core">Inner</button>
<button onclick="showID()" name="Circle" id="shell">Shell</button>
<button onclick="showID()" name="Circle"id="surface">Surface</button>
```

Comment: It'll work if you simply pass the clicked element to the function: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/uz81antk/

Comment: Yes, this worked Thank You Sir.